# Offset between UTM and lat/long coordinates?

Tags: qgis

I need to convert some UTM coordinates to lat/long coordinates in order to write those coordinates into some image exifs.

I used the QGIS tool "Add geometry attributes" to do so and it works as intended, but as soon as I create a new project and add both layers together, there's quite some offset between both data sets (see screenshot).

Any guess what's the reason for that? My guess is that the precision of the lat/long coordinates isn't sufficient? But the QGIS tool doesn't give me the option to set the precision. Anything else? Any other way I can do this coordinate transformation in QGIS?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like very minor offset due to a rounding error. From the image you provided, I can see that the lat/long coordinates go to 5 decimal places. If you want more precise coordinates, use the Field Calculator to add fields with 6 or 7 decimal places.

- Use this expression to calculate Longitude: `x( transform( $geometry , layer_property( @layer_id ,'crs'), 'EPSG:4326' ) )`
- Use this expression to calculate Latitude: `x( transform( $geometry , layer_property( @layer_id ,'crs'), 'EPSG:4326' ) )`

Notes:

- Latitude is the Y coordinate and Longitude is the X coordinate in EPSG 4326.
- If your project CRS is EPSG:4326, you can substitute the variable `@project_crs` for the final parameter (`'EPSG:4326'`). Thanks to [GeoEki](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/50772/geoeki) for this suggestion.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was it...it really just was a precision matter. It didn't work with your suggested expression, but with this slightly modified one `x( transform( $geometry ,  layer_property(  @layer_id ,'crs'), @project_crs ) )`

Comment: Oops. I mixed up `translate` and `transform`. Glad you figured it out. I'll correct the formula in my answer.